# Monetize a PWA - which to use for monetizing a Progressive web app?

Tags: web-applications, admob, adsense

I am building a **PWA** ( Progressive web app) and I'm actually planning to just release the apk and do not use any websites for that matter.

The question is how am I supposed to monetize my PWA?

I am leaning towards **adsense** but I've heard that could be a violation of policy.  Considering the fact that PWAs can be used offline adsense won't make much sense.

Comment: A PWA is not delivered through the app store, nor compiled into an APK.

Comment: I'd suggest to you what I advise in PropellerAds. It's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Far As i Know, PWAs dont have APKs for their installation. They are installed via browsers (Chrome mainly).

Regarding Monetisation, there can be several ways depending upon the tasks performed in your app and your planning like:

1. Ad placement.
2. Directly Charge Consumer.
3. Affiliate some Products for amazon etc.
4. Direct Ads.
5. Direct Affiliate to companies.
6. several others, depending upon your app niche

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm a bit late but I have been searching the same topic but until recently, I found a "solution", **[PropellerAds](https://propellerads.com/)**.

To be honest, it's quite fast to integrate, you just need to verify your site, add like 2 lines of JavaScript code and that's all. Now, is it a good option to use PropellerAds? The answer is yes and no. You will get ads but they will look like these:

[image: example]

In my opinion, they can be tricky because they can bring a bad experience to your users, and in my case, they break my PWA normal behavior.

You might be wondering, does PropellerAds not offer you a kind of banner? Yes but only in very specific circumstances that my app doesn’t meet yet (a high traffic per month). Furthermore, there is no way to easily delete your account or channels, not even change your email. Be careful if you go with this alternative.

I’d be very glad if anyone has another working solution or if you found an alternative and share it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap your PWA in a webview using Cordova, Ionic or Capacitor. This way you will be able to take advantage of the Admob Sdk to monetise your app. On the web version you can use Adsense and then on the native one you can use the Admob Sdk. I used this plugin in one of my Cordova apps before and it works seamlessly for any type of ad https://www.npmjs.com/package/admob-plus-cordova.